# User can not download old modules from sitecore market place

Tags: sitecore-marketplace

Go to sitecore market place site. And try downloading any module.

User is redirected to new market place link mentioned below.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/SearchResults#qr=powershell%20extension

https://www.sitecore.com/products/marketplace?sc_lang=en

And the sitecore modules not found on new site when you search on new platform.

Anyone has face this problem. Below are couple of example

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Secure_File_Upload

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/P/Point_of_Interest_Module.aspx

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx?sc_lang=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is something that can help you.

If you know the URL of the Module then try removing `.aspx` from the URL for example if the module URL is

http://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/L/Language_And_Version_Manager.aspx

then remove the .aspx from the last and try

http://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/L/Language_And_Version_Manager

Here is the accepted solution link for this.

https://community.sitecore.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=4e30a69b1b54d190e55241dde54bcb50

Answer (score 2):

The Sitecore Marketplace is going to or retired already for technical reasons. Sitecore has now the new Developer Portal (https://developers.sitecore.com) and marketplace for pre-built connectors and apps from Sitecore and its partners that extend Sitecore, and make weaving it into client's business easy, fast, and flexible.

Sitecore recommends **GitHub** as a great place to host your modules, and many other community members are already doing this. A lot of community members will have an associated blog article posted somewhere to explain/advertise the module. Make sure your README in your GitHub repo has the information needed for search engines to surface your module to people looking for it!

I think Sitecore added redirects for these marketplace modules and that's why it is redirecting to the product marketplace - https://www.sitecore.com/products/marketplace

> It's a **Hack** but for now, you can run the URL by removing the
> `.aspx` and can download the module or can navigate to the GitHub repo
> from the page.

I hope Sitecore will create some kind of page with links to these modules and GitHub path before completely retiring The Sitecore Marketplace.

Ref - [How to contribute on Sitecore Marketplace now?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29684/how-to-contribute-on-sitecore-marketplace-now)